# Better way to map a deep object to new object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, recursion, mapping

This code works for converting the JSON to an object where each name object turns into the key for either its value, or if it instead has its own element object breaks that out and does the same to its contents.

Is there a better way to do this that would also allow for more extensiblity of the JSON schema?
Is there a way I can get it all down to a simpler function that I can pass the first element and have it convert it down to whatever depth the schema goes?

```js
const fs = require('fs');
{
    let scheme = JSON.parse('{"$schema":{"root":{"name":"THINGY","dtd":{"name":"DOCTYPE","value":"something.dtd","commentBefore":["?xml version='1.0'?","Version NULL"]},"ele":{"name":"REPORT","ele":[{"name":"SEGMENT0","ele":[{"name":"NUMBER1","value":""},{"name":"NUMBER2","value":""}]},{"name":"SEGMENT1","ele":[{"name":"RECORD1","ele":[{"name":"NUMBER1","value":""},{"name":"NUMBER2","value":""}]}]},{"name":"SEGMENT2","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT3","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT4","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT5","ele":[]}]}}}}').$schema.root;
    let depth = 0;

    var compiled = {
        [scheme.ele.name]: scheme.ele.ele.map(function(i) {
            if (typeof i.ele != 'undefined') {
                return {
                    [i.name]: i.ele.map(function(k) {
                        if (typeof k.ele != 'undefined') {
                            return {
                                [k.name]: k.ele.map(function(p) {
                                    if (typeof p.ele != 'undefined') {
                                        return {
                                            [p.name]: p.ele
                                        };
                                    } else {
                                        return {
                                            [p.name]: p.value
                                        };
                                    }
                                })
                            };
                        } else {
                            return {
                                [k.name]: k.value
                            };
                        }
                    })
                };
            } else {
                return {
                    [i.name]: i.value
                };
            }
        })
    };
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(compiled, 0, 2));
```

I should add, this is intended to eventually also apply validation and grab real data when it gets to the string objects.

The output looks like this:

```json
{
    "REPORT": [
    {
        "SEGMENT0": [
        {
            "NUMBER1": ""
        },
        {
            "NUMBER2": ""
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SEGMENT1": [
        {
            "RECORD1": [
            {
                "NUMBER1": ""
            },
            {
                "NUMBER2": ""
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SEGMENT2": []
    },
    {
        "SEGMENT3": []
    },
    {
        "SEGMENT4": []
    },
    {
        "SEGMENT5": []
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you post what the output of this function with your test data looks like?

Comment: It's impossible to read things you wrote but feels that you should recursion instead of copy paste same functions on each level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nina's answer is cleaner but this looks a bit more like your code so I figured I'd post it anyway.

```js
let scheme = JSON.parse('{"$schema":{"root":{"name":"THINGY","dtd":{"name":"DOCTYPE","value":"something.dtd","commentBefore":["?xml version=\'1.0 \'?","Version NULL"]},"ele":{"name":"REPORT","ele":[{"name":"SEGMENT0","ele":[{"name":"NUMBER1","value":""},{"name":"NUMBER2","value":"1"}]},{"name":"SEGMENT1","ele":[{"name":"RECORD1","ele":[{"name":"NUMBER1","value":"2"},{"name":"NUMBER2","value":""}]}]},{"name":"SEGMENT2","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT3","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT4","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT5","ele":[]}]}}}}').$schema.root;
let newScheme = JSON.parse('{"$schema":{"root":{"name":"THINGY","dtd":{"name":"DOCTYPE","value":"something.dtd","commentBefore":["?xml version=\'1.0 \'?","Version NULL"]},"ele":{"name":"REPORT","ele":[{"name":"SEGMENT0","ele":[{"name":"NUMBER1","value":"1"},{"name":"NUMBER2","value":"3"}]},{"name":"SEGMENT1","ele":[{"name":"RECORD1","ele":[{"name":"NUMBER1","value":"4"},{"name":"NUMBER2","value":""}]}]},{"name":"SEGMENT2","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT3","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT4","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT5","ele":[]}]}}}}').$schema.root;

//Yay, recursion!
function mapObj(a, o = {}) {

  let array = o[a.name] || [];

  for (let i = 0; i < a.ele.length; i++) {

    let b = a.ele[i];
    array[i] = b.ele ?
      mapObj(b, array[i]) : {
        [b.name]: b.value
      };
  }
  
  o[a.name] = array;
  return o;

}

let obj = mapObj(scheme.ele);

console.log(obj);
console.log(mapObj(newScheme.ele, obj));
```

Comment: I've switched to using your method since I'm having to do a lot additional parsing in my application of it. Do you know how I might selectively rerun the record sections? I'm trying to use this while also populating the values from a query and I need to continue iterating where I have more records from my query.

Comment: I edited my post. If you run `mapObj` with the old object it will update/add records to the object.

Comment: I posted a new question that has sort of what I'm trying to do with inserting the data. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55734548/8443777

Answer (score 4):

You could destructure the object, get `name`, `ele` and `value` and return a new object with `name` as key and either an array by mapping the objects of `ele` or the `value`.

```js
const
    getData = ({ name, ele, value }) => ({
        [name]: Array.isArray(ele)
            ? ele.map(getData)
            : value
    });

var scheme = JSON.parse('{"$schema":{"root":{"name":"THINGY","dtd":{"name":"DOCTYPE","value":"something.dtd","commentBefore":["?xml version=\'1.0\'?","Version NULL"]},"ele":{"name":"REPORT","ele":[{"name":"SEGMENT0","ele":[{"name":"NUMBER1","value":""},{"name":"NUMBER2","value":""}]},{"name":"SEGMENT1","ele":[{"name":"RECORD1","ele":[{"name":"NUMBER1","value":""},{"name":"NUMBER2","value":""}]}]},{"name":"SEGMENT2","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT3","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT4","ele":[]},{"name":"SEGMENT5","ele":[]}]}}}}').$schema.root,
    result = getData(scheme.ele);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think I'm still a bit fuzzy on functions and expressions like this. Thanks for the elegant solution. I tried a recursive function with a self call and nesting stuff in the return, but when I went to debug it, it wouldn't progress into the function at all, I thought it was because I couldn't do self calls.