# node and parent links

Tags: windows, socket.io, async-await

I have json collection, which is contains nested elements as an array or key value pair and can be nested upto any length. I need to pass through an array, and find the items within it and convert them with their respective values.

For example, in the given below array, I have an Array

One function to just get the values
1. I will pass this array to find out these two cells within the JSON collection and convert them into value. These values can be anywhere in the tree. I need to pick up the cell and their parent node. and it should search them put their respective value in it so it will chanege from ["TRC030-A", "TRSEE050-A"] to [22, 12]

One function to just sum up the values
2. Please note there are collections, and in them, the cell is same. but if I pass the "NSEE050-A","NSEE060-A" in the example, it should pick them and put the value and sum them up

I need to do this javascript recursively.
Kind regards,

```
{   
"MusicVersion": "1.0.0",
"validationVersion": "1.0.0",
"submissionStage": "editing / submitted for approval etc.",
"PiaonoData": { 
         "musicacademies": [
           {
              "name": "Music Name",
            }]
 },
"MainData": { 
  },
  }
```

Comment: What question are you asking? Please post a [mcve] and describe where you've run into trouble.

Comment: I had [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635678/better-way-to-map-a-deep-object-to-new-object/55636142#55636142) for which the answer might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Map` to map the keys in your search-array to their index in that same array. That map will allow to check quickly whether a property in the data matches any property and give its index. It would also work with `indexOf`, but a Map is faster.

For the rest is a recursive function: it can be exited as soon as all keys have been found:

```js
function mapKeys(obj, keys) {
    const map = new Map(keys.map((key, i) => [key, i]));
    const result = [];
    function recur(obj) {
        for (prop in obj) {
            if (Object(obj[prop]) === obj[prop]) {
                recur(obj[prop]);
            } else if (map.has(prop)) {
                result[map.get(prop)] = obj[prop];
                map.delete(prop);
                if (!map.size) return;
            }
        }
    }
    recur(obj);
    return result;
}

// Sample data
const data = {"MusicVersion": "1.0.0","validationVersion": "1.0.0","submissionStage": "editing / submitted for approval etc.","PiaonoData": {"musicacademies": [{"name": "Music Name","id": "Music ID / UPIN","data": "See Example Form Object","SCI040": "newly admitted member"}]},"MainData": {"mainBalance": {"CAATOT" : 0,"AFC020-A": 11,"TRC030-A": 22,"TRC040-A": 33,},"nonMainData": {"TRSEE050-A": 12,"staffEmoluments" : [{"NSEE050-A": 12,"NSEE050-B": 22,"NSEE050-C": 40,"NSEE050-D": 54},{"NGEE050-A": 36,"NGEE050-B": 41,"NGEE050-C": 9,"NGEE050-D": 0},{"NLEE050-A": 1,"NLEE050-B": 3,"NLEE050-C": 7,"NLEE050-D": 9}],"MuiscSpecialPayments": [{"LSRP010-A": 12,"LSRP010-B": 22,"LSRP010-C": 40,"LSRP010-D": 54},{"LDSP010-A": 36,"LDSP010-B": 41,"LDSP010-C": 9,"LDSP010-D": 0},{"LDSP010-A": 1,"LDSP010-B": 3,"LDSP010-C": 7,"LSSP010-D": 9}],"MusicConversions": [{"type": "simple/complex/conversion","TATI010-A": 1,"TATI010-B": 3,"TATI020-A": 7,"TATI030-B": 9}]}},"MusicData": {"AatOverview": { "TATI010-A": 1,"ABCD": 3,"DEF": 7,"KLM": 9},"acOverview":  {"TATI010-A": 1,"ATAATI010-B": 3,"OPQ": 7,"ATAATI030-B": 9,},"musicacademies": [{"name": "Music Name","id": "MusicID","data": "See Example Form Object","MCI040": "Newly admitted"}]},"otherMusicData": { "tbc": null },"MusicCompletionStatuses": { "tbc": null },"MusicValidationExplanations": {"ABC1001": {"fieldValue": "600","userComment": "Extra spend"},"ABS1196": {"fieldValue": "30","userComment": "This is the reason "}},"lastUpdatedBy": "user namer","lastUpdatedDate": "2016-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"};

console.log(mapKeys(data, ["TRC030-A", "NSEE050-A"]));
```